# What is the distinction between a CommandButton's .caption and .text properties in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a CommandButton in Excel and found that both the `.Caption` and `.Text` properties return the same visible text of the button.  Here's the code I used to see the values:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Buttons("My_Command_Button").Caption
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Buttons("My_Command_Button").Text
```

What is the distinction between these two properties and does the distinction matter?

Comment: Good question. I do not see a difference but that's just  based on what I tried. Try `dim sh as Button` and `set sh = ActiveSheet.Buttons("My_Command_Button")`. Maybe in such a way you get more information. You can also change caption/text of the button in this way.

Comment: I think you have a form control Button, not an ActiveX CommandButton, if you're referencing it from the `Buttons` collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trick question. If you examine the `CommandButton` coclass definition in fm20.dll (or in the VBE's Object Browser, you'll find that it doesn't ***have*** a `Text` property:

[image: CommandButton in Object Browser]

The ActiveX controls are composited via extension at run-time, so properties that are specific to how the control is embedded in a spreadsheet, or a `UserForm`, (or anything else for that matter) are actually being driven by the OLE container that "owns" the object. It makes a certain amount of sense if you think about it - why should a `CommandButton` care what it's `Left` or `Top` property is? You shouldn't ever need to have a `CommandButton` that isn't the child of another parent window or container, and it isn't the responsibility of the `CommandButton` to determine where it is within the window - that's the window's job. It's part of the reason why they don't have public constructors:

```
Dim example As CommandButton
Set example = New CommandButton     '<-- Nope.
```

If you *were* able to instantiate a parentless `CommandButton`, you'd find that the only way to set the text on the button would be to set the `.Caption` property. That's because at a deep down Windows API level, it is a window (in that it has an hWnd), and the convention is for windows to have a `Caption` property. How that is *displayed* is implementation specific.  In this specific instance, they can be treated interchangeably, but the `.Caption` property is the "real one", and the `.Text` property mirrors it. Unless you're doing something extremely bizarre with it (like getting its hWnd and using that with the Windows API directly), they are for all intents and purposes the same thing.