# display textbox shape value

Tags: vba

When you add a textbox shape to the screen, you can use one of the following two methods to edit the displayed string:

[textbox].textframe.characters.text

or

[textbox].textframe.characters.caption

Is there any benefit of using one over the other?  Any limitations?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237543/4088852).

Comment: Amazing!  thank you!!